# Find the root word of the word using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, nlp, data-cleaning

I want to match the phrase "glass coffee cups" matched with the title, "Glass Coffee Cup" since cups are a plural form of cup. So despite the plural form, it will still be considered as a match for its singular form. Other examples include keywords, "coffee glasses" and "tooth" with the titles, "Coffee glass" and "Teeth" respectively. The possible keywords to be evaluated with the main title could be more than a thousand. 
The solution that I could think of is to get the root word for both so they could be matched. Or change both of them () to their plural forms. 
Is it possible to find the root word of a word using Google Apps Script? Will Google Cloud Natural language API fit for it? Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: I dont think this is possible through the use of Apps Script or Google Cloud Natural Language API as per reading through their documentation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158534/find-the-root-word-of-the-word-using-google-apps-script). You can read more about it regarding the scope of Cloud Natural Language on their documentation

Comment: This might be interesting to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778836/programmatic-way-to-determine-related-words  You might be able to find webservices which you could access via urlfetchapp which could assist you in this quest.

Comment: The technical term for what you are looking for is ´lemma´, so ´lemmatisation´ might be a good search term.